# HTML5 Canvas no method 'toDataURL'

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

My Code is like this

```
    <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
    <img id="canvasImg" onclick="myFunction()" alt="Right click to save me!">
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        function myFunction() {
            var c = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
            // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
            var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
            // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
            // so it can be saved as an image
            document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i click on `canvasImg` its throwing an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'toDataURL'
```

I have made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSYwb/) 
Can any one point out whats going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VSYwb/5/)**

`document.getElementsByTagName`  returns array of elements objects, and no array objects have method toDataUrl

instead of this

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
```

use

```
 var c = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function myFunction() {
         var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
         var img = document.getElementById("canvasImg");
         context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
```